# A (relatively simple) Riddle

Tags: riddle

*Hopefully this isn't too obvious, and if it is - oh well, it is my first one:*

> Sometimes you leave me.
>
> But I cannot possibly leave you.
>
> Sometimes you follow me.
>
> But I can also follow you.
>
> My tense is both from the past and of the future, and I can also be
>   progressive.

**What Am I?**

Comment: -1: This seems *way* too broad. If you ever have to say "this fits all the clues, but isn't what I had in mind", then you need to narrow it down or your question will be closed.

Comment: @Deusovi, well technically they didn't say it fit all the clues, just that it fits well, but it may still be too broad. Hard to say.

Comment: (Also, hints are not considered part of the riddle for purposes of being too broad.)

Comment: Amruth A's answer doesn't really fit the fourth clue (but the others did fit)

Comment: @John no. I don't *think* a dream can follow someone, but you *never can tell*  (those sneaky dreams) - but no, dream isn't correct.

Comment: @X-27, footprint seems to work pretty well except you're talking about tenses.

Comment: The last line hasn't narrowed down the enough - a majority of the answers can be nouns or verbs. Until the riddle is made sufficiently narrow, I'm going to have to close it.

Comment: Between Amruth's gas and Vucko's drinking, I think this might be the puzzle of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be:

> Trail

Sometimes you leave me.

> Perhaps usually you leave a trail.

But I cannot possibly leave you.

> Your trail doesn't often leave you, but I suppose your scent could?

Sometimes you follow me.

> You can follow a trail

But I can also follow you.

> Trails follow you

My tense is both from the past and of the future, and I can also be progressive.

> Hmm...

Comment: Correct! this is exactly what I had in mind. for the last clue, think Trail - Trailed (past tense) Will Trail (Future tense) and Trailing (Progressive)

Answer (score 3):

Can it be

> A shadow?

Sometimes you leave me.

> You leave your shadow when you enter a dark room

But I can not possibly leave you.

> Your shadow can never leave you and be somewhere else

Sometimes you follow me.

But I can also follow you.

> Self-explanatory depending which angle the sun/light shines, your shadow is either behind, or in front of you

I don't have the explanation for the last one :/

Comment: Your on the right track - something a person leaves, but that they can also follow. But it can be either a verb or a noun (hence the clue on the tense of the verb)

Comment: Oh. I'll take a better look tomorrow. Too intoxicated at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> GRAVITY

Sometimes you leave me.

> We can leave earth gravity.

But I can not possibly leave you.

> Gravity tries too pull us.

Sometimes you follow me.

> In space shuttle we revolve around earth because of gravity.

But I can also follow you.

> Gravity is everywhere around us.

I come both from the past and future, and I can also be progressive.

> Is it Gravity exists from beginning of time and will exists in future.

Comment: +1. This fits well, but isn't what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say

> Footprints

Sometimes you leave me.

> We leave footprints.

But I cannot possibly leave you.

> Our footprint is obviously pretty stuck to us.

Sometimes you follow me.

> You might follow someone's foot steps/prints.

But I can also follow you.

> We leave a trail of footprints.

My tense is both from the past and of the future, and I can also be progressive.

> Our foot sizes can progress?

Comment: This fits perfectly, as well as Trail (because, if you think about it, you are leaving a trail of footprints)

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer-

> farting

Sometimes you leave me.

> Yes I can fart.

But I can not possibly leave you.

> Can't fart unless we are willing to.

Sometimes you follow me.

> Thinking ,Where is bad smell coming from??Follow it.

But I can also follow you.

> Bad luck , you move anywhere the smell follows you.

My tense is both from the past and of the future, and I can also be progressive.

> farted - will fart - farting ..

Comment: @X-27 I think this is perfect fit!! or else give hint

Comment: @ Amruth A, Can we get that in plural future perfect progressive tense please?

Comment: @John is it related to grammar , or it can be DIFFUSION OF GASES

Comment: @ AmruthA, it's related to me really wanting to know if such a phrase has ever been uttered!! You could be the first!